# Proper format for processing external data from API in Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am new to learning Rails and how to process data from an external API. I am needing to parse information from a certain Google API and display all of that information on my index view - ex: use the certain google api to show all events on the events controller index method and render it in the index view for that controller.

I'm currently getting a NoMethodError for a string (referencing the @googleUrl variable). So it is not properly parsing and rendering the information and displaying it in my view. What would be the best (Rails) way to parse the information and access it? Would I need to add in a step to JSON.parse googleUrl? I've seen various posts also about using a gem called Unirest, but did not know if there was another way, or best practice way. Or jBuilder?

In events controller:

```
def index
  base_url = 'url given from google api to use'
  key = ENV['GOOGLE_API_KEY']

  @googleUrl = base_url + key

respond_to do |format|
 format.html
 format.json {render json: @googleUrl}
 end
end
```

Index view example for events controller:

```
  <div>
    <ul>
      <% @googleUrl.each do |event| %>
       <li> <%= event.title %> </li>
    <% end %>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `googleUrl` is just a string. you can't call `each` on a string

Comment: Thanks @jpriebe- I was able to figure it out to get the formatted JSON back .... now just need to figure out how I can access certain parts of the data in the view ... thank you!

Comment: Np. If you show us what the data looks like we can probably help you parse it.

Comment: @jpriebe - This is what part of the data looks like. I know how to manipulate the data structure some to access a particular value (ex: title). But in order to do so, I have to pass in the index (ex: @books['items'][0]['volumeInfo']['title']) in the view in my each loop. I don't want to do that though cause I want all of the titles, not just the one with the first index. Thoughts? http://jsfiddle.net/qxfwfc0t/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate through the titles like this:

```
<% (@books['items']).each do |item| %>
   <li> <%= item['volumeInfo']['title'] %> </li>
<% end>
```

Comment: Thank you @jpriebe! Worked beautifully. When I was trying to write that, I was forgetting the parenthesis in the beginning. Awesome, thanks again!